# Understanding gradle multiproject building

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have the following project tree:

```
root
 |
 |--MP
 |  |
 |  |---build.gradle
 |
 |--API
 |
 |---build.gradle
 |
 |---settings.gradle
```

MP::buiild.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':API')
}
```

root:build.gradle:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin : 'java'
    repositories{
        mavenCentral()
    }
    version = '1.0'
    jar{
        manifest{
            attributes 'Gradle': 'Multiproject'
        }
    }
}
```

root::settings.gradle:

```
include 'API', 'MP'
```

The thing is if we delete one of these three files `gradle build` task will fail. So it's not clear to me how `java plugin` builds the project. I run `gradle build` for `MP::build.gradle`, the following output was produced:

```
:API:compileJava
:API:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:API:classes
:API:jar
:MP:compileJava
:MP:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:MP:classes
:MP:jar
:MP:assemble
:MP:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:MP:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:MP:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:MP:test UP-TO-DATE
:MP:check UP-TO-DATE
:MP:build
```

So, the first what we need to do when we run `gradle build` for `MP::build.gradle` is to resolve all dependecies. As far as I understand it means to load jars from an external repositories and, if need, to compile `jar`-files from a separate projects. In my case it's just to get `API` project `jar`-file.

So my question is what is the subsequnce of actions to compile that `jar`. What will happens when `gradle` came across the `compie project(':API')`. It's looking for the `gradle.settings` file and report an error if there isn't or it's looking for `build.gradle` in the root directory first?

Answer (score 1):

To have quick look of what is going on in a java multiproject:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

"For the subsequence of actions to compile that jar." Look at the diagram
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

And for crossproject dependencies
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:cross_project_configuration 
Quote: "By default, the configuration of all projects happens before any task is executed"

Comment: Let me ask you question. Where did you find an answer to my question in the first two references you provided? Could you cite the actual answer?

Comment: Please provide some quotes, as links come and go in the web

Comment: @cfrick The thing is these questions appear while I was reading the  chapter 7. I've build these projects, but there are no any details about how gradle exactly work with subprojects. I'd like to understand how it works in details.

Comment: The first link give you a global view of a java multiproject. A quote of how the dependencies is handled in the second link: "By default, the configuration of all projects happens before any task is executed". For Java, there is a full diagram of all phases.

Comment: Sorry, a quote of how the dependencies are handled in the third link: "By default, the configuration of all projects happens before any task is executed..."

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already figured it out .

So the gradle build life cycle explains it ... the life cycle is as below 
 1) initialisation
 2) configuation
 3) execuion .

for your particular case  of a multi project build , what happens is

1) initialisation ::
   here the settings.gradle is searched for no matter from which project you run it (it always tries to find settings.gradle file when you run a task and includes those projects defined in its include directive.)
 2) configures
   it creates the task tree based on the task you have tried to run and its dependencies.
 3)execution ::

runs the task tree.

Please let me know if this is helpful.

You can read this page for more clarity.

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html